# easy_install not installing on the right path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, easy-install

So I got python3.3.2 from source easy install-3.3 and I'm trying to get them to work nicely, but I'm having an issue in one of the servers. In Ubuntu I just do this:

```
# Install python 3.3.2
cd /tmp/
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar xvf Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd Python-3.3.2/
./configure --prefix=/usr/
make
make test
sudo make install
```

To get python to work... this is fine, then:

```
# Install easy_install for python 3.3.2
cd /tmp/
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
tar xzvf distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
cd distribute-0.6.49
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

And then I can see something weird on the output:

...

```
Extracting distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg to /usr/bin/lib/python3.3/site-packages
distribute 0.6.49 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/bin/bin
Installing easy_install-3.3 script to /usr/bin/bin
```

...

Why is easy_install getting placed in /usr/bin/**bin**???? WTH??

Also, everything I install with easy_install goes there:

```
sudo easy_install-3.3 gunicorn
Searching for gunicorn
Best match: gunicorn 18.0
Processing gunicorn-18.0-py3.3.egg
gunicorn 18.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing gunicorn_django script to /usr/bin/bin
Installing gunicorn script to /usr/bin/bin
Installing gunicorn_paster script to /usr/bin/bin

Using /usr/bin/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gunicorn-18.0-py3.3.egg
Processing dependencies for gunicorn
Finished processing dependencies for gunicorn
```

Although:

**which python3** and **which easy_install-3.3** both point to **/usr/bin** as expected!

Surely all the binaries are there but they are not reachable on PATH... and I don't want to edit my PATH env variable... any ideas on what is going on??

Comment: Can you do `which python3` please?

Comment: I'm in /usr/bin/python3 as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely nuked my python installation! and now it is working. I do not have a clue what was happening but stackoverflow users care about solving thinks first... here is what I did:

1. Clear every single trail of python3... **BEWARE WITH THIS COMMANDS**, THEY WILL BLOW UP YOUR PYTHON3 INSTALLATION.

   > ```
   > sudo apt-get remove python3
   > sudo apt-get remove python3.2*
   > sudo apt-get remove python3.3*
   > sudo apt-get remove python3.4*
   > sudo apt-get remove python-sphinx
   > sudo apt-get autoremove
   > sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/bin/
   > sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3*
   > sudo rm /usr/bin/python3*
   > sudo reboot
   > ```
2. Reinstall the dependencies to build python

   > `sudo apt-get build-dep -y python3 python-setuptools`
3. I install 3.3.3 since 3.3.2 was giving me issues with some tests.

   > ```
   > cd /tmp/
   > wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2
   > tar xvf Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2
   > cd Python-3.3.3/
   > ./configure --prefix=/usr/
   > make
   > make test
   > sudo make install
   > python3 --version
   > ```
4. Now easy_install!!!

   > ```
   > cd /tmp/
   > wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
   > tar xzvf distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
   > cd distribute-0.6.49
   > sudo python3 setup.py build
   > sudo python3 setup.py install
   > ```
5. Fix some permission issues up

   > ```
   > sudo chmod +r /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/python_dateutil-*-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
   > sudo chmod +r /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/python3_digest-1.8b4-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
   > mkdir -p $HOME/.config/ipython
   > sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/.config/ipython
   > sudo chmod g+w $HOME/.config/ipython
   > sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ipython3 /usr/bin/ipython  # this is more for me... maybe you don't want this one... it will open ipython3 on `ipython` command.
   > ```
6. Try it!

   > ```
   > sudo easy_install-3.3 ipython gunicorn
   > ```

And everything is in order now!

```
Adding gunicorn 18.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing gunicorn script to /usr/bin
Installing gunicorn_django script to /usr/bin
Installing gunicorn_paster script to /usr/bin
```

Check that **/usr/bin** out!!!! Don't you just wanna lick it!?

Ha!